Lost update problem - version in incoming command model
I have some problem... I need to write an update method that will update user data. I have three requirements for this task:
1. there cannot be a race condition
2. if the current version of the object is provided in the request - it will be committed and the version will be increased by 1 in the database
3. when a wrong version of an object is provided - an ObjectOptimisticFailureException exception is to be thrown
I used @Version on my entity for this purpose, but the requirement is that the request must include a command that is to be mapped to the entity... and this is where my problem begins - the version field from the command is not used for anything, so why such a requirement at all? Maybe there's something I don't know?
public class Person implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName

    @Version
    protected Long version;

@Data
public class UpdatePersonCommand{

    private Long version;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}

Controller:
   @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> update(@PathVariable Long id, UpdatePersonCommand command) throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(personService.update(id, command));
    }

Service:
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public PersonDto update(Long personId, UpdatePersonCommand command) throws IOException {
       try {
           Person person = personRepository.findById(personId)
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(MessageFormat
                           .format("Person with id={0} not found", personId)));
           return objectMapper.updateValue(person, command);
       } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
           throw new ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException(e.getMessage(),"The person has been modified by another transaction");
       }
    }

Manually checking whether the version number of the entity and the command are equal is not an option, because it causes a race condition...
I tried to use native query but this is not a safe solution either...

Where is the Problem? Just set version from UpdatePersonCommand to Person, If Version is different - you will get your OptimisticLockException by update.

But in JPA spec you have: " An entity may access the state of its version field or property or export a method for use by the application to access the version, but must not modify the version value. With the exception noted in section 4.10, only the persistence provider is permitted to set or update the value of the version attribute in the object." (Note: Section 4.10 refers to batch updates which ignore the version attribute.)

If you have open session in view - you don't need update version. But you leaved Spring context -so you have to save your version on Frontend and then set version on entity. In other fall you lost your Version Information
